# Rails:Attached file is not showing in edit profile page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am working in a job site project where candidate can upload there resume which is working perfectly fine but when candidate want to edit his profile then resume file fields is not showing the already attached resume.

Resume file field is displaying empty . I am using paperclip for uploading resume.

Please assist something how can i get the attachment in edit form as well.

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: please add some code first... we can't help you without looking at your code first

Comment: I think code i am using is fine because this is an issue with file upload in rails using paperclip if any one has handled this issue in past and shorted out then pls help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show the image you have uploaded, you'll need to [use the `.url` method on the `paperclip object`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#show-view):

```
<%= image_tag Model.image.url %>
```

That's the best I can do without any extra code